# Road Graph Export Empty QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing

Exporting the results of a shortest path analysis through the Road Graph plugin in QGIS 2.0.1 results in an "empty" layer.

After running teh shortest path calculator, I selected export --> new temporary layer.  I select the coordinate system (WGS84 - UTM18N)

Note in the photo, that a path on my roads vector layer is selected (red) by Road Graph, but the attribute table is empty.  When I save this temporary layer permanently, the layer remains empty as well.

Please send instructions on how to make the export work/another way to save shortest paths as separate shapefiles.

[image]

Comment: I have this problem, too. The routing with the road graph plugin is working as I am used to from previous QGIS-Versions. But the export doesn't work. Neither the export to a temporary file nor the export to an existing shape-file. First I tried the standalone 64bit-version of QGIS 2.0.1, after this I installed the 32bit-version on another computer with the OSGeo4W installer. The result is the same on both computers: The attribut table stays empty, no geometries created during the routing calculations can be exported.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem this week, and eventually installed QGIS 1.8 (didn't even need to uninstall 2.0). In v1.8, Road Graph exported my shortest path results to a shapefile just fine, which I was then able to use in 2.0.

Comment: Thus it appears to be a bug related to QGIS 2.0 and should be reported. Maybe the original developer has time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a different tool, see my answer concerning a routing script for the Processing toolbox [How do i draw a route on Quantum GIS between nodes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76710/how-do-i-draw-a-route-on-quantum-gis-between-nodes/82907#82907)