# Creating route between specific nodes based on sequence in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, network

Right now I am working on a project related with the german railway network. I have a layer call `"Stops_1_2"` which contains the trip id, the stop sequence and the name of the station. I have another layer called `"Railway_Germany"` which I got from the Deutsche Bahn. I would like to create routes based on the common field trip_id and based on the network `"Railway_Germany"` so that I can get paths on the real network and not just straight lines.

I don't know how to adress this problem. I tried using shortes path (`'Point to Point'`) but the problem is that I can only choose two points and I have a lot of data to do that manually.

This is the attribute table of my point layer....so what I need is for example create a for trip_id=10 following its stop_sequence, then create another route for trip_id=100 following the stop sequence and another route for trip_id=1001 following the stop sequence and so on that I cover all my trip_id.

[image: attribute_table]

This is my railway network and the stops

[image: layers]

Is there a way to this on QGIS? Like I said I am new using QGIS and my programming skills are not good at all. (If there is maybe a solution with other software (like ArcMap) it would be helpful also)

Comment: As a light workaround you may try using ['Points to path'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) with `"trip_id"` as a *Group field* and `"stop_sequence"` as a *Order field*. Then creating a buffer around those paths and afterwards selecting from `"Railway Germany"` within those buffers.

Comment: Maybe check these threads https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76710/99589, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56575/how-to-route-railcars-along-railroads

Comment: Also check this article https://anitagraser.com/2013/10/19/a-routing-script-for-the-processing-toolbox/. Before applying a script you can additionally break your point layer into groups of points with [Split Vector Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#split-vector-layer).

Comment: I tried but the problem is that I got straight lines that are sometime do cross a lot features of my network that I dont need....I mean...I have route A_1 that for example Start in city A then go the B thne to C and the D...but then I have route A-2 with the same star at A and the end at D without the stops in between...points to path generates this straight line between A-D and the output just crosses a lot of features that I dont need...

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look at the links you sent!!

Comment: Also do not forget about GRASS GIS in the Processing Tool, they have many good libraries for network analysis, e.g. [`v.net`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.html)